# Attaching a log file in Team City using email notification

Tags: email, teamcity

Team City- I have tried to attach log file in Team City by email notification.I am facing difficulties in this.

I tried placing the e-mail templates in the home directory of Team City($HOME\config_notifications\email).

I have also tried placing the templates in the project itself.

A part of the Sample Template:

```
<events>
   <event type='build_started'>
     <ref template='build_started_tpl'/>
   </event>
</events>
<templates>
   <template id='build_started_tpl'>
<subject>Build {PROJECT_NAME}::{BUILD_CONFIG_NAME} {BUILD_NUMBER} started.</subject>
<body>Build {PROJECT_NAME}::{BUILD_CONFIG_NAME} {BUILD_NUMBER} started.
Build results: {BUILD_RESULTS_LINK}
 </body>
</template>
```

Both ways are not working.Can somebody help me with this.Being a fresher,can someone explain me in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this? I would like to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a separate application for sending email in Team City.

Comment: Can you share more on this answer

Comment: An external application in .net called send email is created. Then I called the application in team city scripts.

Comment: No. You can create send email application in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `config/_notifications/email/build_failed.ftl` in the HOME directory. In the global body HTML insert

```
<#list build.buildLog.messages[1..] as message><#-- skipping the first message (it is a root node)-->
<#if message.status == "WARNING"> <font color="#FF9900">${message.status}</font>: <font color="#FF9900">${message.text}</font></br></#if>
<#if message.status == "ERROR"> <font color="#FF0000">${message.status}</font>: <font color="#FF0000">${message.text}</font></br></#if>
</#list>
```

This will mail the errors and warnings in your build.